# Update.php gets "The page isn’t redirecting properly" error page

Tags: 7, migrations, updating

I recently moved our site to a new hosting company.  After uploading all the files and importing the database I get this notice when I try to Run Updates and/or accessing the update.php page.

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> An error occurred during a connection to oursite.com.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
> accept cookies. Try Again(button)

I moved the site from Dreamhost to A2Hosting.  It is on A2Hosting that I am getting this error.

The guys at a2Hosting said that the problem was not on the server side.

The site is currently on Drupal Ver. 7.82 and running php 5.6 on both servers.  All modules were updated prior to moving things.  Everything still works fine on the old servers.

Not sure if it is related to this problem, but we are also having issues with Flags not working on the a2Hosting server.   The error we get when trying to use any flag is:

> Notice: Undefined index: token in flag_page() (line 25 of
> /home/username/public_html/sites/all/modules/flag/includes/flag.pages.inc).
> Bad token. You seem to have followed an invalid link.

I am stumped and could really use some insight as to what I have done wrong.  I have searched everything I could read that may bring up a solution and am still not finding one.  Anything would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The message you posted regarding update.php does not originate from Drupal itself. One way forward is to check what logs on the network tab of the developer tools for whatever web browser is saying that. The network tab log needs some interpreting if you are not well versed in HTTP. In fact the main console log of the developer tools may have sufficient logging to diagnose.

Comment: Thank You for the insight.  The network tab shows 21 302's of it trying to access the update.php?op=info file.  Also, the main console only shows: This error page has no error code in its security info aboutNetError.js:523:13

Comment: 302 codes are temporary redirects. You'll have to look further into each 302 that is logged to understand the details of what is happening, in particular, to where the response is redirecting the browser.